# Executing Query contain string without using quotes

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

So i am trying to delete data in database based on two things.

First is a combox box which selects the column name and second is the value whose row is to be deleted.

```
(@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " + var + " LIKE " + textBox1.Text + ";");
```

Now the problem here is that as long as the value in the textBox is numerical this query will work fine. However if it is a string value the query will fail because i haven't inserted the single quote.

Is there anyway i can make just a single unified query for handling both numerical and text data.

Comment: The answer depends on your choice of database access tools. You might want to read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection though.

Comment: Don't care about SQL Injection.

Comment: You.... dont care about SQL Injection?! Ok, so I choose var `foo` and enter into textbox1 `'foo';DELETE * FROM Contacts`. Now im guessing you care!

Comment: nahh i will just show the exception. Its just a stupid assignment.

Comment: Assignment or Missle control system - you should still care about SQL Injection vulnerability!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, let's not do this. We need to just use parameters.

```
(@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " + var + " LIKE @" + var + ";");

...

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + var, textBox1.Text);
```

So the overall code might look something like this:

```
string varName = string.Format("@{0}", var);
string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE {0} LIKE @{0}", var);

using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(varName, textBox1.Text);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}
```

Also, have a look at [this post on my blog](http://learncsharp.org/how-to-properly-and-safely-access-a-database-with-ado-net/). It talks about what I just went through, as well as how to **safely** do a `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`parameterized query`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    @"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " + var + " LIKE @param", connection));

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", textBox1.Tex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes arounf the value so that it will accept string as well numerical values

```
(@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " + var + " LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "';");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 (@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " + var + " LIKE " _
 + iif(isnumeric(textBox1.Text),textbox1.text, "'" +textbox1.text +"'" + ";");
```

That's a vb-centric IIF statement, but there's an equivolent in C#.

Answer (score -1):

```
(@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " + var + " LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "';");
```

Answer (score -1):

U can check the value whether its integer or string and format different query accordingly.U can use like operator also.

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = Console.ReadLine();
int myval;
String query="";
if(int.TryParse(str,out  myval))
   query=@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " + var + " LIKE " + myval + ";";
else
   query=@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " + var + " LIKE '" + str + "';";
```